# What are valid values for the TemplateArn property of the AWS SES v2 sendEmail method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, specifications, amazon-ses

The AWS SES v2 (!) API specification states that for the `sendEmail` method the parameter object can contain a [`Content.Template` object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference-V2/API_Template.html). This object in turn has a `TemplateArn` property, which is simply described as "The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the template." by the linked specification.

As the SES v2 API has no methods defined which allow interaction with email templates, as the SES v1 API had, my question is: where can I define an email template using the v2 API or where can I get valid values for the `TemplateArn` property from?

Answer (score 1):

- In the AWS Console, open *IAM*, select *Policies* from the sidebar, click *Create policy* button.
- In the *Create Policy* screen, select *Service:* `SES v2`, *Actions:* `SendEmail`. See image 1 below (from September 2022).
- In the *Resources* section, click on `Add ARN`.
- A modal will open where you provide Region, Account ID, and Template name. At the top you will see the ARN that gets constructed from the data. See image 2 below (from September 2022).

[image: AWS IAM Create Policy screen with SES v2 and sendEmail action selected]

[image: Modal that constructs the ARN from region, account id, and template name]

Comment: As I don't use AWS currently anymore, I'd accept this answer once someone else confirms this to be working! <3